# Convert JQuery tree plugin to Angularjs Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview

Below is the JQuery tree plugin which i used in previous project

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree/

Now i am in need to convert it to the Angularjs Directive.

Can any one help me how to achieve this please?

Comment: Ask a question about a specific problem. Don't ask ppl to do your work for you

Comment: @cathal I am just asking how to achieve this

If you know any simple tutorial link just share it would be much helpful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got an solution and that too pretty simple one

```
App.directive('filetree', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: 'true',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function () {
                $('#container_id').fileTree({
                        root: '/',
                        script: '/Exm/source/vendors/couple/jqueryFileTree.jsp',
                        expandSpeed: 1,
                        collapseSpeed: 1,
                        multiFolder: false
                }, function(file) {
                        alert(file);
                }); 
            });
        }
    }
});
```